# Explain containerization to a moron

Tags: ssl, containers, tls1.2

I'm not actually a moron, but I am a designer, and for the purposes of this conversation, that's close enough.

Can someone try explaining containerization, specifically how it relates to spinning up servers and SSL/TLS certificate installation?

Much obliged.